# Disappearing value in a matrix (but same number of row) in R

Tags: r, matrix

Something incredibly weird is happening in my file. Some values are disappearing but I have the same amount of row. Somes values are still in the matrix, so I don't understand.

```
# Data : meps >> https://github.com/JMcrocs/MEPVote/raw/master/meps.rds

> str(meps)

'data.frame':   784 obs. of  2338 variables:
$ mepid: num  197701 197533 197521 187917 124986 ...
$ EPG  : chr  "GUE.NGL" "GUE.NGL" "GUE.NGL" "GUE.NGL" ...

> mepsMatrix <- as.matrix(meps)
> str(mepsMatrix)

chr [1:784, 1:2338] "197701" "197533" "197521" "187917" "124986" "197529" "197468" " 96706" " 88715" "197416" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:784] "197701" "197533" "197521" "187917" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2338] "mepid" "EPG" "1" "2" ...

> nrow(meps)
[1] 784
> nrow(mepsMatrix)
[1] 784
> 28229 %in% meps[,'mepid']
[1] TRUE
> 28229 %in% mepsMatrix[,'mepid']
[1] FALSE
```

The weirdest part is that I can find it with the RStudio viewer.

Can someone help me, please? I would be grateful!

Comment: what R version are you using?

Comment: look: `" 28229" %in% mepsMatrix[,'mepid']` is TRUE. your problem is related to how Numbers are converted to chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 20), b = c("a", "b"))
m <- as.matrix(df)

2 %in% df[, "a"]
#> TRUE
2 %in% m[, "a"]
#> FALSE
" 2" %in% m[, "a"]
#> TRUE
2 %in% trimws(m[, "a"])
#> TRUE

m
#>      a    b  
#> [1,] " 2" "a"
#> [2,] "20" "b"
```

Apparently `as.matrix` forces the same padding to keep the same string lengths when converts to character.

Comment: Thanks to you, I used meps$mepid = trimws(meps$mepid) before doing my matrix and now everything runs smooth.